# Origin of the practice of Piśṭa paśu in Vedic Yajnas?

Tags: vedas, other-religions, animals, yajna, vedic-rituals

Piśṭa paśu is said to be the replacement of animals with images of animals made of corn-flour in Vedic rituals. My question is, in which scripture is this practice mentioned and what are the details associated with the practice. Also, is the practice an internal evolution within Hinduism or was it mainly due to [Jain](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=aktdBheKI-IC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=pista%20pasu&source=bl&ots=GeAXJIf5qc&sig=v5R5mTSY9z_sbuC1y4II3lMc7Ew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAmoVChMIieis9Y6DxwIVwaSUCh2jbg9d#v=onepage&q=pista%20pasu&f=false) or [Buddhist](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4UG2_fvimjMC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=pista%20pasu&source=bl&ots=HgYllbHEGw&sig=jLpI2Ewht8Z0c5yP4Iaat2fdM7U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwA2oVChMIieis9Y6DxwIVwaSUCh2jbg9d#v=onepage&q=pista%20pasu&f=false) influence?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40869/20829. The evidence of the Aitareya Brahmana text shows that this was an internally recognized alternative to animal sacrifice independent of Buddhism or Jainism.